# after live sass compiler, sftp don't upload compiled file

Tags: sass, sftp

**Do you read the FAQ?**
Yes.

**Describe the bug:**

Live sass compiler with https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler make style.css.min file but this file do not auto upload

in sftp.json (accesses are hide, only one file do not upload after save):

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "host": "host",
  "protocol": "ftp",
  "port": 21,
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "remotePath": "/remotePath/",
  "uploadOnSave": true,
  "watcher": {
    "files": "/style.min.css",
    "autoUpload": true
  }
}
```

**What i need to do to make auto upload generation file style.min.css?**

Answer (score 0):

Config for SFTP:

```
{
        "name": "Project name",
        "host": "host server",
        "protocol": "ftp",
        "port": 21,
        "username": "login ftp",
        "password": "password_ftp",
        "remotePath": "/",
        "ignore": ["..."],
        "uploadOnSave": true,
        // Watcher for auto upload after compile scss
        "watcher": {
            "files": "**/*",
            "autoUpload": true,
            "autoDelete": false
        },
        "useTempFile": false,
        "openSsh": false 
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).